# Erro ao subir container mysql (com volume)

Tags: mysql, windows, docker

Boa Noite. Estou aprendendo docker e não consigo subir um container MySQL quando adiciono um mapeamento de **volume**. Segue os erros e o arquivo docker-compose.yml abaixo. Estou utilizando o docker toolbox no windows 10.

```
mysql_teste  | 2018-01-21 22:37:02 7ff0031ee740  InnoDB: Operating system 
error number 22 in a file operation.
mysql_teste  | InnoDB: Error number 22 means 'Invalid argument'.
mysql_teste  | InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
mysql_teste  | InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-
system-error-codes.html
mysql_teste  | 2018-01-21 22:37:02 32 [ERROR] InnoDB: File ./ib_logfile101: 
'aio write' returned OS error 122. Cannot continue operation
mysql_teste exited with code 141
```

Comment: Como está sua imagem/compose, altera algo nela? O volume é de alguma versão do MySQL diferente da que está tentando subir agora? Inclua mais informações, só com isso aí é meio difícil. De toda forma, veja esta pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713146

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente sobrescreveu uma pasta de sistema do MySQL e não a pasta de dados. A princípio o erro ...

`mysql_teste  | 2018-01-21 22:37:02 7ff0031ee740  InnoDB: Operating system 
error number 22 in a file operation.
mysql_teste  | InnoDB: Error number 22 means 'Invalid argument'.`

...denota uma falha de configuração que pode variar desde a inexistência do arquivo de configuração, passando pela formatação errada (CRLF vs LF), entre outras coisas. Ou ainda o mysql recebendo um parêmetro (o nome do arquivo de cnf ) errado/inexistente.